# custom text filename postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem, I generate a function that creates a temporary table, and I use it to create a text file, until there is everything well generated that is what I need.

But in the name of the file that I create, I need to pass a parameter (basically the value of a column in a table in my database), but when trying to pass a value, I get an error or simply create the file with a name that It has special characters.

And so far tried the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_campos_base2() 
RETURNS TEXT AS $$

DECLARE
    registro TEXT DEFAULT '';
    var1 TEXT;
...
BEGIN

    var1 := 'LO_LOGRE';
....
EXECUTE $$COPY (select * from tmp1) to '/tmp/editores/prueba_$$ || var1 || $$_OMS.txt' WITH DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'LATIN1'$$; 
..... 
COPY (select * from tmp1) to '/tmp/editores/prueba_|| var1 ||_OMS.txt' WITH DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'LATIN1';
....
```

Until try with bash syntax:

```
COPY (select * from tmp1) to '/tmp/editores/prueba_`var1`_OMS.txt' WITH DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'LATIN1';
....
```

Is it possible to customize the file name with the COPY command?

Answer (score 0):

eg:

```
do
$$
declare
var1 text := 'some';
begin
execute format('copy pg_database to %L','/tmp/'||var1||'.csv');
end;
$$
;
```

and check:

```
t=# \! head -n 2 /tmp/some.csv
postgres    10  6   C   UTF-8   f   t   -1  12668   858 1   1663    \N
t   10  6   C   UTF-8   f   t   -1  12668   858 1   1663    \N
```

Comment: Vao Tsun 
Thank you very much, it worked perfectly, I solve my problem.